# Javascript functions question, could someone possibly help explain?

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to learn Javascript and understand that functions are one of the most important aspects of the language but I have to say Im finding it very hard to understand them especially when different parameters are being used here there and everywhere.

I have been looking at this code which I read in another stack overflow post regarding closure and cant understand how 16 is alerted, I have used console.log to work out what value is being used at each point and seem to get a total of 17, could someone possibly explain?

```
function foo(x) {
 // console.log(x); = 2    
 var tmp = 3;
 return function (y) {
  // console.log(y); = 10
  alert(x + y + (++tmp));
  // console.log(++tmp); = 5?
 }
}
var bar = foo(2);
bar(10);
```

If anyone can offer any wisdom about functions that might make things start to make sense for me it would be really appreciated.

Kyle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alert()` command really pops up 16.

`++tmp` is preincrement statement - first, it increments the value (from 3 to 4) and then continues with execution of the line.

So `2 + 10 + 4` is passed to the `alert()`.

The `console.log(++tmp)` below the alert logs 5, because the `tmp` variable is incremented again, from 4 to 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try to log

```
console.log(tmp);
```

Instead of

```
console.log(++tmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

`foo(2)` initializes `tmp` to 3 and `x` to 2 within the scope of the returned function. 
`bar(10)` then adds 2, 10, and the result of incremented `tmp` (which went from 3 to 4 before being added to `x` and `y`).

so the alerted value will be the sum of 2 + 10 + 4..  16.